# why my file is not displaying correct space after opening the program in read mode. some content are declaring correct but some are not

Tags: c, file

```
CALchart()
{
  char ch3;
   FILE *fp3 =fopen("calorieschart.txt","r");
   
   if(fp3==NULL)
   {
       printf("file doesn't exists");
       exit(1);
   }

   while((ch3=fgetc(fp3))!=EOF)
   {
       
       printf("%c",ch3);
   }
   fclose(fp3);  
}
```

Here is [the file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jRyVtG1VsXFhv55ebWi64zhs3amuUy4e/view?usp=sharing)

I want to display as it is in a proper rows and column format or aleast the way it is.I want to fix this  code and wanted to know why it's happening.

Comment: What is the difference between the output you expect and the output you get?

Comment: The file you linked is a text file containing TAB `'\t'` characters, and you might need to expand them, but TAB isn't always so simple, often aligning to a modular position rather than a fixed number of spaces (or the other way round).

Comment: I think that one problem is that `fgetc` doesn't return a char.

Comment: Based on Tim's observation, try `int ch3;` This will allow it to match `EOF` correctly.

Comment: Weathervane can we read the tab in the program to fix it

Comment: Note that error messages should be printed to `stderr` and should end with a newline.  Your function would be more flexible if you passed the file name in as an argument rather than hard-coding it.  You should specify an explicit return type.  If your compiler accepts this without complaint, it means you're compiling with C90 mode, which is probably older than you are (or possibly you are not using standard C at all).  You should be using at least C99 and preferably C11 or C17.  You should be using `void CALchart(void)` (or, preferably, `void CALchart(const char *filename)`).

Comment: @Onkar you can: `if(ch3 == '\t')`

Comment: Yes @jonathan leffler i am getting an implicit declaration error .how to fix it.thankx for the advice

Comment: @weather vane thx

Comment: Declare the function before defining it, or make the function `static` in the file — and include the `(void)` notation (if you keep to a hard-wired file name). If the function will be used outside the source file, put `extern void CALchart(void);` in a header, and use the header in both the file where the function is defined and the file(s) where it is used. Otherwise, use `static void CALchart(void) { … ]` and ensure that definition appears before it is called, or use `static void CALchart(void);` at the top of the file and `static void CALchart(void) { … }` to define the function.

Comment: Also, if you use GCC or Clang, add `-Werror` to your compilation options — then you won't be tempted to use a program where the compiler is giving warnings.  At this stage of your career, if the compiler deigns to give a warning, it has spotted an incipient bug and you should fix it.  Heck, even after 30+ years of coding in C, I assume that if the compiler is giving a warning, it means there's a bug in the code.